# Tableview size change when i touch the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have got 2 `TableViews` in the `ViewController`(1: `tableView` 2: `tableview2`) - the size of each one in the `MainStoryBoard` is 40, BUT in the code the size of each one is by its content size (for example: if i got 4 rows and each row is 22 so the `tableview` is 88).

When I run the app I see the size of the `Tableviews` as I want - by its content size, but when I click the screen to scroll down (I also got ScrollView) both `tableviews` become smaller to the size of the `MainStoryBoard`, which is 40.

What can I do to **do not make the tableview smaller when I click it**?
Here is my code so far:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height)
    tableview2.frame = CGRectMake(tableview2.frame.origin.x, tableview2.frame.origin.y, tableview2.frame.size.width, tableview2.contentSize.height)
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
        if tableView == tableview2 {
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height)
        tableview2.frame = CGRectMake(tableview2.frame.origin.x, tableview2.frame.origin.y, tableview2.frame.size.width, tableview2.contentSize.height)
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableview2.reloadData()
        } else {
            tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height)
            tableview2.frame = CGRectMake(tableview2.frame.origin.x, tableview2.frame.origin.y, tableview2.frame.size.width, tableview2.contentSize.height)
            tableView.reloadData()
            tableview2.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use autolayout ?

Comment: I tried now to cancel the autolayout and it worked! But what if I need to use the autolayouts later?

Comment: Yeahthat probably not what you want. What are your constraints exactly on the tableview ?